# How to take \varkappa from XITS when using Asana math?

Tags: unicode-math, latin-modern

I don't like `\varkappa` in Asana math font and want to substute it with `\varkappa` from XITS math font. Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[version=xits,Color=006600]{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[version=asana,Color=000066]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[version=lm,Color=660000]{Latin Modern Math}
\newcommand{\mykappa}{\mbox{\mathversion{xits}$\varkappa$}}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
\mathversion{asana}
\[
  \vec{\varkappa}=\varkappa\vec{n}
  \qquad
  \vec{\mykappa}=\mykappa\vec{n}
\]

\mathversion{lm}
\[
  \vec{\varkappa}=\varkappa\vec{n}
  \qquad
  \vec{\mykappa}=\mykappa\vec{n}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Is it a better solution? In particular, how one can redefine `\varkappa` instead of defining new command `\mykappa` as in the example above?**

By the way, Latin Modern Math is missing bold varkappa as shows output generated with this MWE:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[version=Asana,Color=000066]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[version=xits]{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={"003F0,"1D6DE}]{XITS Math}%%%% only for kappa

\newcommand{\mykappa}{\mbox{\mathversion{xits}$\varkappa$}}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
\mathversion{Asana}

\[
  \mbfvarkappa=\upvarkappa\vec{n} \qquad  \vec{\mykappa}=\mykappa\vec{n}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what I had in mind: `\varkappa` still is taken from Asana Math. Is it possible to redefine `\varkappa`?

Comment: `\let\varkappa\upvarkappa` _after_  `\mathversion{Asana}`

Comment: Still not working for \mathbf{\varkappa}.

Comment: sure, it is `mbfvarkappa`

Comment: I believe that logics is broken here. If I take both `\mbfvarkappa` and `\upvarkappa` from XITS, \mathbf{\varkappa} shoud take `\mbfvarkappa` (ie "1D6DE) from XITS rather than from Asana as it occurs in fact. Am I right?

Comment: use `range={"003F0,"1D6DE,\mathbfit}`

Comment: It is still not working for me. I tried also `range={"003F0,"1D6DE,"1D718,"1D752,"1D78C,"1D7C6,"0039A,"003BA,"1D6CB-"1D7FF}`, which enlists all occurances of `\..varkappa`s. Fortunately, `\vec{\mykappa}=\mykappa\vec{n}` works as intended.

Comment: I wrote that you should insert the `,\mathbfit` into the `range`

Comment: I tried `,\mathbfit`. No result.

Comment: give a complete example ... it works for me